# DataTables.net remove double quotes from CSV export

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using datatables.net to export a csv file from a table like so:

```
             var buttonCommon = {
                 exportOptions: {
                     format: {
                         body: function (data, row, column, node) {
                             return data.replace("\"", "");
                         }
                     }
                 }
             };

            <%--Data tables--%>
            var table = $('.table').DataTable({
                "paging": false,
                "ordering": false,
                "info": false,
                "searching": false,
                bSortCellsTop: false,
                dom: 'Bfrtip',

                buttons: [
                    $.extend(true, {}, buttonCommon, {
                        extend: 'csvHtml5'
                    })
                ]

            });
```

This SHOULD result in a csv file with no double quotes, yet they appear....
I've looked and I can't find anyone running into this issue?  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
"Receipt","Total","Date","","","","Total","Type","GL Code","Amount","","",""
"g092920","","09/29/2020","","","","","","106.104.0000","$37.52","","",""
"","","","","","","","","106.369.0009","$0.00","","",""
"g092920","","09/29/2020","","","","","","","$0.00","","",""
"g092920","","09/29/2020","","","","","","106.208.1000","$2.45","","",""
"g092920","","09/29/2020","","","","","","106.347.2040","$20.07","","",""
"g092920","","09/29/2020","","","","","","106.347.2050","$0.00","","",""
"g092920","","09/29/2020","","","","","","106.347.2050","$15.00","","",""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is all you need to stop using the double quotes around strings, note the fieldBoundary option:

```
            var table = $('.table').DataTable({
            "paging": false,
            "ordering": false,
            "info": false,
            "searching": false,
            bSortCellsTop: false,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',

            buttons: [
                $.extend(true, {}, buttonCommon, {
                    extend: 'csvHtml5',
                    fieldBoundary: ''
                })
            ]
        });
```